# create unique id variable based on existing id variable

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Trying to make a more simple unique identifier from already existing identifier. Starting with just and ID column I want to make a new, more simple, id column so the final data looks like what follows.  There are 1million + id's, so it isnt an option to do if thens, maybe a do statement?

ID  NEWid

1234   1

3456   2

1234   1

6789  3

1234  1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trivial data step solution not using monotonic().

```
proc sort data=have;
by id;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id;
if first.id then newid+1;
run;
```

Comment: I like this solution better.  Single data step (and considering you might already sort by ID somewhere else, maybe the only necessary step).

Answer (score 2):

using proc sql.. 
(you can probably do this without the intermediate datasets using subqueries, but sometimes monotonic doesn't act the way you'd think in a subquery)

```
proc sql noprint;

    create table uniq_id as
    select distinct id
    from original
    order by id
    ;

    create table uniq_id2 as
    select id, monotonic() as newid
    from uniq_id
    ;

    create table final as
    select a.id, b.newid
    from original_set a, uniq_id2 b
    where a.id = b.id
    ;

quit;
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying to avoid using proc freq and then exporting results to excel because sooner or later the data will be too large.

Comment: FWIW, monotonic() is undocumented and not considered a 'production' function, so use at your own risk.

Comment: Right, the question was tagged with proc sql, so i used proc sql.  Using a data step and "_ N _" would work as well